# Element-wise product of two series with one of them divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Suppose we have two series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k$. Both of them have nonnegative terms. If $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k = \infty$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k b_k < \infty$, then $\liminf_{k \to \infty} b_k = 0 $.

I have an idea of showing the statement by contradiction. Suppose $\liminf_{k \to \infty} b_k = \beta > 0$. By definition, there are at most finitely many $b_k's$ with $b_k \le (\beta - \beta/2)$. Let $I = \{ k \in \mathbb{N}: b_k \le \beta/2 \}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k b_k &\ge \sum_{k \in (\mathbb{N} \setminus I)} a_k b_k \\
& \ge (\beta/2) \sum_{k \in (\mathbb{N} \setminus I)} a_k \\
& > \infty.
\end{align*}
I am wondering whether there exists more direct method to show the statement. Thanks.

Comment: What's not to like about this argument?

Comment: @user159517: One reason is I could not find a proof in textbooks. The statement seems very elementary. I am interested to know whether there are some direct techniques to cope with this kind of scenarios. Putting in other words, I want to learn some direct proof techniques if existing.

Comment: @jing007 I was say that your proof is already quite direct. Although you framed it as a proof "by contradiction", you never needed to assume a contradiction. The argument was conservative enough with its assumptions that it actually serves as a direct proof of the contrapositive.